# Численные методы (метод хорд)

Tags: c++, численные-методы

Было задание найти корни уравнения методом хорд. Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double f(double x)
{
    return pow(cos(x), 3) + x * x * sin(x) + 20;
}

double findRoot(double (*f)(double), double a, double b,
                double eps = 1e-5)
{
    double t;

    while (fabs(b - a) >= eps)
    {
        t = a + (f(b) * (b - a)) / (f(b) - f(a));

        if (f(a) * f(t) < 0)
        {
            b = t;
        }
        else if (f(t) * f(b) < 0)
        {
            a = t;
        }
        else
            return t;
    }

    return t;
}

int main()
{
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    double a, b;
    cout << "\nEnter the limits,\n\nLeft limit,a= ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "\nRight limit,b= ";
    cin >> b;
    double t = findRoot(f);
    cout << "x=" << t << "f(x)=" << f(t) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибки выдает следующие

```
chord2.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
chord2.cc:36:22: error: too few arguments to function ‘double findRoot(double (*)(double), double, double, double)’
double t = findRoot(f);
^
chord2.cc:11:8: note: declared here
double findRoot (double (*f)(double), double a, double b, double eps=1e-5) {
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, что не так.

Comment: У Вас формула неправильная (опечатка, наверное) `t = a - (f(a) * (b - a)) / (f(b) - f(a));` Но ошибка компилятора, конечно, не из-за этого.

Comment: @Karina Еще пара замечаний, имена ваших фун-й не информативны. И лучше будет если вы напишите отдельный модуль для этих функций. и если у вас есть константы то лучше их вынести 'eps=1e-5'.

Answer (score 5):

Если **только понять, что сообщает компилятор** - то тут все просто: функция

```
double findRoot (double (*f)(double), double a, double b, double eps=1e-5)
```

у вас принимает 4 аргумента; в крайнем случае - с учетом значения по умолчанию - три. Вы же вызываете ее

```
double t = findRoot(f);
```

с единственным аргументом, не указав ни `a`, ни `b`...